# Using " ,".join in Django splitting every character, rather than item in list

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a list of book genres I'm trying to display in in template using this code

```
{% if title.my_books.genre.all %}
     <li class="list-group-item">
     <kbd>Genres</kbd>
     {% for genre in title.my_books.genre.all %}
         {{genre.genre}}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}</li> 
{% endif %}
```

My goal is to display the items like so `Autobiography, Biography, Memoir`. And the above code DOES THAT. However, I've been asked to alter the code to use Django's join template tag detailed here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#join

Let's the say the items of the list are ['Autobiography', 'Biography', 'Memoir']

Obviously, if I don't have this line `{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}` and just have `{{genre.genre}}` in the for loop,

the values will display like `Autobiography Biography Memoir`

However if I alter the above code like so following Django's docs:

```
{% if title.my_books.genre.all %}
     <li class="list-group-item">
     <kbd>Genres</kbd>
     {% for genre in title.my_books.genre.all %}
         {{ genre.genre|join:" ," }}
      {% endfor %}</li> 
{% endif %}
```

The output on the template looks like this:

```
A ,u ,t ,o ,b ,i ,o ,g ,r ,a ,p ,h ,y B ,i ,o ,g ,r ,a ,p ,h ,y M ,e ,m ,o ,i ,r
```

How can I properly display the values like so: `Autobiography, Biography, Memoir` using Django's join template tag? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the way you did it treats every `genre.genre` as a source for `join`, so it basically spreads every `genre` separatedly. Remebmer, that in Python strings can be interpreted as list of characters. So if you want to do it properly, you should pass the genres as a list of all genres in context.

views:

```
context['genres'] = Title.my_books.genre.all()
```

or even better add a method to your Model:

```
YourModel(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_all_genres(self):
        return self.genres.all()
```

and then in template:

```
{{ yourmodel.get_all_genres|join:', ' }}
```

It might now be precise, because I don't know your exact models/views, but I hope you understand that solutions.

Comment: What if each Genre was a clickable link? How will join work then?

Comment: @prsnr it should work as generic Python function. If you want to join list of strings, then it will make one string joined  with separator between each substring.

Comment: Where will "a href" go?

Comment: @prsnr If it is a part of the string, then it will be still a part of the string. Just read that:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#join - and stop asking silly questions, please :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you said but if you have list = ['Techno', 'House', 'Drum & Bass'] then {{ list|join:', ' }} will convert it to Techno, House, Drum & Bass, but there will be no links. I want each style to be a clickable link and with join, you cannot do it.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

#### First: Generate a list in model and join it in template

In your model

```py
class YourModel(model.Model):
    
    @property
    def genres_list(self):
        return list(self.genres.all())
```

In your template

`Genres: {{ genre.genres_list|join:" ," }}`

#### Second: Generates a str directly in python and show it in template

In your model

```py
class YourModel(model.Model):
    
    @property
    def genres(self):
        return ", ".join(list(self.genres.all()))
```

In your template

`Genres: {{ genre.genres }}`

I prefer the second because if you want to show the same string on different places only need to include the property

Comment: Thanks. Is there no workaround to this outside of altering the models? I'm sort of past that point. I've tried `{{title.my_books.genre.all|join:', ' }}` and I get `My_BooksGenre object (6), My_BooksGenre object (9)`. Which is sort of what I want, but how can I extract the value from those My_BooksGenre objects

Comment: It's difficult because in the template to do a join we need a list of values and query.all returns a qs of objects, maybe you need to create a custom filter `join_by_value` that receives the qs and the field that you need and returns the joined string, more reference here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/

Comment: What if each Genre was a clickable link? How will join work then?